# AppEngine's entity group write limit is very limiting in real life application?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm thinking about introducing entity groups in my application to enable strong consistency. Propose I have an Order entity and a OrderRow entity with each Order as a parent for it's OrderRows. Then it would be normal to update the Order with the sum of all OrderRows when adding an OrderRow.

But because the datastore is limited to 1 write per second, each time I edit/add an OrderRow it would take at least one second because of the updating of the Order.

Is this correct? If so, the one second limit is extremely limiting because it's very often you update two entities within the same entity group in one user request?

Comment: The limit is (roughly) 1 update per second, but that doesn't mean each write takes a whole second to complete. Writes are a lot faster than that!

Comment: Ok, thanks. But as I found out, if I do the writes within a transaction, I can do as many writes as I like and don't worry about the limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is within a single request, then you can run them all within the same transaction, (which is the purpose of the entity group).

Comment: So it is not limited to a write per second, it is one transaction per second?

Comment: it's one write per second **per entity group**, when you have entity group, you can kind of think of them like one big entity.

Comment: and several writes in a transaction only counts as one write? or is everything in a single user request counted as only one write?

Comment: within a transaction yes. I recommend watching [the more 9s talk from this point](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xO015C3R6dw&feature=player_embedded#at=343)

Comment: here is a direct link to the time where they discuss the write limit:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xO015C3R6dw#t=335