# ndb and consistency: Why is happening this behavior in a query without a parent

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm doing some work with Python and ndb and can't understand why. I'll post the cases and the code above:

## models.py

```
class Reference(ndb.Model):
  kind = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
  created_at = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
  some_id = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
  data = ndb.JsonProperty(default={})
```

**Those tests are running in the Interactive console and --high_replication option to dev_appserver.py:**

## Test 1

```
from models import Reference
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
import random

some_id = str(random.randint(1, 100000000000000))
key_id = str(random.randint(1, 100000000000000))

Reference(id=key_id, some_id=some_id, kind='user').put()
print Reference.query(Reference.some_id == some_id, Reference.kind == 'user').get()

# output:
# >> None
```

Why ????? Now, let's add a sleep(1) before printing:

### Test 2

```
from models import Reference
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
import random
from time import sleep

some_id = str(random.randint(1, 100000000000000))
key_id = str(random.randint(1, 100000000000000))

Reference(id=key_id, some_id=some_id, kind='user').put()
sleep(1)
print Reference.query(Reference.some_id == some_id, Reference.kind == 'user').get()

# output:
# >> Reference(key=Key('Reference', '99579233467078'), createdAt=datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 31, 16, 24, 46, 383100), data={}, kind=u'user', some_id=u'25000975872388')
```

K, let's assume it's emulating the time for spreading the document to all Google's tables, I will never put a sleep into my code, ofc. Now, let's remove the sleep and add a parent!

## Test 3

```
from models import Reference
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
import random
from time import sleep

some_id = str(random.randint(1, 100000000000000))
key_id = str(random.randint(1, 100000000000000))

Reference(id='father', kind='father').put()

Reference(parent=ndb.Key(Reference, 'father'), id=key_id, some_id_id=some_id, kind='user').put()
print Reference.query(Reference.some_id == some_id, Reference.kind == 'user', ancestor=ndb.Key(Reference, 'father')).get()

# output:
# >> Reference(key=Key('Reference', '46174672092602'), createdAt=datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 31, 16, 24, 46, 383100), data={}, kind=u'user', some_id=u'55143106000841')
```

Now that's confusing! Just set a parent and give me strong consistency! Why ?
And if it is required for give strong consistency, why not having all documents the same parent when inserting it in datastore, by default ?
Maybe I'm doing it completely wrong and there is a way to do it better. Please, someone guide me!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Because an entity group has also write limitations. See also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049717/appengines-entity-group-write-limit-is-very-limiting-in-real-life-application

Comment: I can't understand how write limitations can influence this, even reading your link. Can you please explain ? Thanks.

Comment: The is a video in the link of my above answer, explaing the limitations: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xO015C3R6dw

Comment: Ok, so it was designed this way and I'm making it right ? Makes no sense to me yet not having a default parent/ancestor so Test 1 will not happen ever. "Writes are sync and you always fetch once it's put." but in my test, when I try to get(), it's not put yet. If it has write limitations, put() should wait before returning. Am I right ?

Comment: This is relevant I thinK http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448366/in-practice-how-eventual-is-the-eventual-consistency-in-hrd

Comment: also try it deployed instead of on devserver, if you have not already.

Comment: Note that a query.get is not a get in the put/get sense. There is no guarantee on when index is updated, but it's usually reasonably fast, as you've seen in #2.

Comment: Deploying it won't change anything, because I'm starting the dev_appserver.py with --high_replication that emulate the datastore. Now I've tried the read_policy=ndb.EVENTUAL_CONSISTENCY but it did not work for Test 1

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that tesdal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ancestor queries operate in the same entity group (and therefore physical proximity) and are strongly consistent.

In test 1 the HRD might not see the put() since it is eventually consistent due to it's distributed nature.

In test 2 the HRD has enough time to become consistent so you see the entity in the query.

In test 3 you place it in the same entity group so it is strongly consistent.

**Q**: Why not have everything in the same entity group?
**A**: GAE can't distribute a massive dataset unless there are a bunch of entity groups (then they can push them out to tons of different servers).  Entity groups should be just as large as you need them to be and no larger (G sometimes uses the example of putting a users "messages" under a User object).  Also, since writing to a member of an entity group locks the whole group you face write speed limitations (like 1 write/sec if I remember, Alfred has a talk on it).

**Q**: My get() didn't get the object, isn't is supposed to?
**A**: No, only get's by key are strongly consistent, you did a query().get() which is really just shorthand for LIMIT 1.

Comment: Nice. Is there any "right" way to achieve that strong consistency ? Am I ok with that approach or will I have problems in the future ? I need certainty :) Thx

Comment: Check the Sharding Counters pattern if you need strong consistency.

Comment: For certain you have strong consistency when you do an ancestor query and get-by-key.  So if you need a "group" of things to always be consistent put them in the same group. Otherwise use keys.

Comment: The *only* way to guarantee strong consistency is to use ancestor queries -- but this constrains your schema and the queries you can do, of course. Perhaps you should learn to live with eventual consistency?