# Odd App Engine NDB behavior w.r.t. get_or_insert and transactions

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, app-engine-ndb

I have what boils down to these helper methods on an `ndb.Model` class:

```
@classmethod
@ndb.transactional(retries=2)
def new(cls, *args, **kwargs):
  internal_name = kwargs['internal_name']
  new_company = cls.get_or_insert(internal_name, **kwargs)
  new_company.put()
  return new_company

@classmethod
@ndb.transactional(retries=2)
def get(cls, internal_name):
  result = cls.query(cls.internal_name == internal_name)
  if result.count() != 1:
    raise Exception("this is a problem");  
  return result.get()
```

I wrote a test to verify my assumptions:

```
def testCanCreateRetrieveCompany(self):
  company = self.models.Company.new(internal_name="google", description="search engine")
  reread_company = self.models.RichCompany.get("internal_name")
  self.assertTrue(True)
```

However, this fails with the `this is a problem` exception every time!

However, if I change the test to:

```
def testCanCreateRetrieveCompany(self):
  company = self.models.Company.new(internal_name="google", description="search engine")
  company.put()
  reread_company = self.models.RichCompany.get("internal_name")
  self.assertTrue(True)
```

this seems to pass. I have absolutely no idea why this passes when the first one doesn't. Also, removing the `@ndb.transactional` operator seems to make this work. Except for I obviously want this to be transactional.

Not sure what's going on. I know there are caveats in the docs around reads in transactions (only ever see original read-state of transaction) but I wasn't aware there were any such caveats for writes. Does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 1):

So after a bit more digging, I think I'm just seeing that the darn updates might be transactional, but are still, in fact eventually consistent - that is, just because the method is transactional, doesn't mean the update made is going to be strongly consistent. I ended up adding a parent/ancestor component to the company keys (so all company objects share a single ancestor) and that gives me the effect I want. See:

[ndb and consistency: Why is happening this behavior in a query without a parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630886/ndb-and-consistency-why-is-happening-this-behavior-in-a-query-without-a-parent)

Comment: Yes you have worked it out. The reason the second example always works is because you are performing a get which is always consistent, whereas the first example you use a query which is only consistent when you use an ancestor query.